# jQuery show / hide multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help in expand/collapse div using jQuery. Here is the problem.

I have an HTML page showing car names and their description as shown below.

1. When the user clicks on any carTitle div, corresponding carDetail div should be expanded (if already collapsed). When the user clicks on that div again, the corresponding carDetail div should be collapsed.
2. Initially, carToyota div should be expanded on pageLoad, and other divs are collapsed
3. User can keep multiple divs expanded at the same time

```js
var collapsed = false;

$(".carTitle").on('click', function(e) {
  collapsed = !collapsed;
  var carDetailsDiv = $(event.currentTarget).next();

  if (collapsed == true) {
    $(carDetailsDiv).hide();
  } else {
    $(carDetailsDiv).show();
  }

  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carItem01_container">
  <div id="carToyota" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Toyote
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carToyota_show" class="carDetails">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carItem02_container">
  <div id="carMazda" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Mazda
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carMazda_show" class="carDetails">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carItem03_container">
  <div id="carVolvo" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Volvo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carVolvo_show" class="carDetails">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code does not work as expected. Can anybody help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default keep all `.carDetails` div as hidden.

Keep `open` class on first car div.

Remove/Add `.open` class on the `carDetails` that is clicked.

```js
$(".carTitle").on('click', function(e) {
  var carDetailsDiv = $(event.currentTarget).next();
  if ($(carDetailsDiv).hasClass('open')) {
    $(carDetailsDiv).removeClass('open');
  } else {
    $(carDetailsDiv).addClass('open');
  }

  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.carDetails {
  display: none;
}

.carDetails.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carItem01_container">
  <div id="carToyota" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Toyote
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carToyota_show" class="carDetails open">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carItem02_container">
  <div id="carMazda" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Mazda
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carMazda_show" class="carDetails">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carItem03_container">
  <div id="carVolvo" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Volvo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carVolvo_show" class="carDetails">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Define your own class called `collapsed`, and set it to `display: none`

```css
collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, you can use jQuery's [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to toggle this class, while also being able to simply add the class to the `carDetails` divs to hide them by default

Finally, you can use `$(this).next()`, rather than `event.currentTarget.next()`

---

Here's the Demo:

```js
$(".carTitle").on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

```css
.collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carItem01_container">
  <div id="carToyota" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Toyote
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carToyota_show" class="carDetails">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carItem02_container">
  <div id="carMazda" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Mazda
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carMazda_show" class="carDetails collapsed">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carItem03_container">
  <div id="carVolvo" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Volvo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carVolvo_show" class="carDetails collapsed">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.toggleClass()` is the cleaner solution

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Also, if this answer has helped you, could you mark it as accepted - This will reward both you and I with some reputation, and will mark your question as solved. [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var collapsed = false;

$(".carTitle").on('click', function(e) {
  collapsed = !collapsed;
  var carDetailsDiv = $(event.currentTarget).next();

  $(this).siblings('.carDetails').toggleClass('show');

  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.carDetails {display:none;}
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carItem01_container">
  <div id="carToyota" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Toyote
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carToyota_show" class="carDetails show">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carItem02_container">
  <div id="carMazda" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Mazda
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carMazda_show" class="carDetails">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="carItem03_container">
  <div id="carVolvo" class="carTitle">
    <div class="carName">Volvo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="carVolvo_show" class="carDetails">
    <div class="carDescription"> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this one i have using toggle class in your description div ....